# Proving $\| x\| -\|Bx\| \leq \| x-Bx\|$ when $\|B\| \leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

> If $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb R^n$, and  $\|B\| \leq 1$, Can we prove the following statement? $$\|x\| -\|Bx\| \leq \|x-Bx\|$$

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vectors $x, y$ in a normed vector Space we have
$$
\lVert x \rVert - \lVert y \rVert \leq \lVert x - y \rVert
$$

as a direct consequence of the triangle inequality. No information about $B$ is needed.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left\| x\right\|=\left\| x-Bx+Bx\right\|\leq\left\| x-Bx\right\|+\left\|Bx\right\| $$

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the [reverse triangle inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)